# Show Dropdown Menu Only on Active Nav Link

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using the following `CSS` to enable `dropdown` menus when you hover instead of clicking on a link:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

It works great, but I want the `dropdown` menus to appear (hover or click) only on a link in the `nav` when it's currently active. The reason is that when I hover on a link, the `dropdown` shows anchor links to jump to specific sections on the page. I don't want anchor links for other pages to show when you're not on that page.

Comment: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: what happens to mobile/tablet users only using touch?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the `active` class in your `:hover` selector, assuming that the active class name is `.active` and it is applied on the `li.dropdown` then you selector should be:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown.active:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

This is an example of course, you'll have to adjust it to fit your case.